# Addition of values from two files shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I have 2 files with data in below format.
File1.txt

```
        abc , 234
        bcd , 457
        xyz , 123
```

File2.txt

```
        abc , 23
        bcd , 458
```

Now, I am looking for following out :-

```
       abc , 211 ( diff of file1 and file2)
       bcd, -1
```

and

```
sum of file1 values present in file2    =  691 (abc count + bcd count in file 1 )

sum of file1 values present in file2    =  481 (abc count + bcd count in file 2 )
```

I know using grep -f we can merge these two files but how to do addition and substraction I am not sure.

Any help will be much appriciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) command will join two files using the first field as the common key by default.

Then the subtraction could be done by [shell arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04).

```
join -t , File1.txt File2.txt |
while IFS="$IFS," read -r key val1 val2; do
    printf '%s , %s\n' "$key" "$((val1-val2))"
done
```

Comment: Sorry for delay .. But this is not working. .. join: output/test1.txt:4: is not sorted:

Comment: @user2854333 Then you need to sort the files first. This can be done inline with Bash process substitution `join -t , <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt)`.